# Counting data from a date range where dates have times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that looks like this

```
=COUNTIFS(MachineData!$N:$N,"*london*",MachineData!$C:$C,">="&(DATE($Q$23,$Q$21,$Q$19)-30),MachineData!$C:$C,"<="&((DATE($Q$23,$Q$21,$Q$19))))
```

Where

```
Q19= 26
Q21= 03
Q23= 2021
```

So I am trying to count everything from `24/02/2021 to 26/03/2021`

and for some reason I am one number off, instead of counting 51 it is counting 50 and I don't know why.

There are times on the dates it is comparing to so I don't know if this has something to do with that.

Comment: `DATE` is usually year, month, day and you have day, month, year ...

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Sorry, I typed that wrong, but the order of the date is right, but it is still counting it wrong for some reason.

Comment: You have to subtract `31` if you want to include the first date, e.g. if you use `TODAY()` in one cell and `TODAY()+1` in a second cell then the difference is `1`, and not `2`.